# How to custom search function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-criteria

Because the **search** of Magento 2 works wrong with my shop, I want a **custom search** function in Magento 2 but I don't know it where.

Please help me, where is function in vendor

Answer (score 0):

You can find that function in the module Catalog search

> Folder: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search

I hope it helps you.